# Change toast notification icon in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, toast

I've developed a wpf application and on that application I'm using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications for toast notification. But I don't know how do I change the notification icon on the toast header(Marked on the uploaded image). I know it's use the app icon but what I want to achieve I want to add a different icon on that toast. How do I achieve it any please help me.
[Here is the toast notification screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtuLp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is your WPF app's icon in your settings.  If you want it to be *different* from your application's icon, I don't think there are any exposed properties or methods to achieve that. However, if you just want it to be the *same* as your app's icon, go to the Solution Explorer, right-click your project, choose "Properties".

Under the "Application" tab, you'll see the setting for this icon.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Using this I have set a icon which color is red. But on toast notification the color is changes from red to light blue. How do I force to keep the icon color red on the toast notification also.